# Get invited users from Twilio Channel

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I have a Twilio channel and I'm trying to get its invited users, but I'm not sure how to do this:

```
    let messagingClient = this.state.messagingClient;
    messagingClient.getUserChannelDescriptors().then(channels => {
        let channelsHash = {};
        channels.items.map(channelDescriptor => {
            var channel = channelDescriptor.getChannel().then((channel) => {
            channelsHash[channel.uniqueName] = channel;
            console.log(channel.getInvited()) // print invited users
            });
        });
```

What would I replace the `channel.getInvited()` by? It seems like Twilio channels do indeed have such a property, as there is an invited resource here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/invites#action-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid that right now the JavaScript SDK does not have a method to retrieve the invited users. In order to get this functionality right now, you will need to use the REST API.

Getting invited users from the SDK is on the backlog though, so keep an eye on the [library releases](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/changelogs/javascript).

**Edit**

Using the REST API to get the invited members:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# Initialize the client
account = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
token = "your_auth_token"
client = Client(account, token)

# Retrieve the channel
channel = client.chat \
                .services("ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") \
                .channels("CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
invites = channel.invites.list()
```

Comment: Thanks philnash! Do you have a link to function in the REST API that I can use to do this?

Comment: What language are you using on the server?

Comment: I'm using python/flask

Comment: Added an example in Python. Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: Is this answer still up to date, or has this since been added to the JS SDK?

Comment: @RYFN I just checked [the channel docs for the latest JS SDK](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.3.4/docs/Channel.html#getMembers__anchor) and I see nothing for getting invited members.

Comment: @philnash thank you for checking! :) we ended up using the REST API as described